# TestComplete C#script runtime error. Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: c#, testing, runtime, coded-ui-tests, testcomplete

During script execution in TestComplete, I encounter an error when displaying the desktop application window. TestComplete throws an error: "testcomplete c#script runtime error. object doesn't support this property or method" at the moment of checking whether the window exists.

```
    while (!p["WaitWinFormsObject"]("ConfigStatusDialog",1000)["Exists"])
       w["Keys"]("[F2]")
```

Name of my Window is ConfigStatusDialog and it is visible in applicattion (in TestComplete "Exists" is True.

[image]

Comment: Hi @kollodziej, just an idea / a guess: Sometimes TestComplete does not necessarily recognize the exact line in the code that is causing the problem. 
Is perhaps the variable w in your code undefined? 
Maybe one more little thing: Your while loop is not secured against 'eternal success'. I mean if after thirty thousand times w["Keys"]("F2") the configuration dialog still exists (for whatever reason), then a stackoverflow (I love that word :-)) can indirectly cause nonsense. (?). I hope, this helps. Regards.

Comment: @primehunter unfortunately changing it didn't help